# Localization of months for clndr.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

I'm running a plugin called [clndr.js](http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/) on one of my projects. Changing the language of the days isn't too hard and can be done by inserting the following line:

```
daysOfTheWeek: ['Z', 'M', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'V', 'Z'],
```

however, i'd like to create an array for months as well. Any thoughts on how to display the names of the month in another language?

Answer (score 2):

Already fixed.

It's located at the depending library moment.js ;)